# Binding a Dictionary that is contained in a class to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagrid

I have a list of the following data structure, that I want to display in a datagrid:

```
public class receiver
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Mail { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> ReplacementText { get; set; }
}

public void Init()
{
  List<receiver> receivers = new List<receiver>();
  // add some instances of receivers

  MyDataGrid.DataContext = receivers;
}
```

Let's assume, in the ReplacementText are the following entries: {City, Leipzig}, {Greeting, Mr.}

Then I want to display the following:

```
| Name  | Mail     | City    | Greeting |
-----------------------------------------
| Frank | i@me.com | Leipzig | Mr.      |
```

The user should be able to edit all the data. Obviously, I cannot simply bind the list as shown in my example above. Also, the entries in the ReplacementText dictionary are dynamic (i.e. the user can add more keys, which then also should be visible in the datagrid). Any idea, how I could achieve such a behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

My aproach

1. convert the `Dictionary` to a `DataTable`

   `DataTable dt = ConvertTo<String>(receivers[i].ReplacementText) ;`
2. bind your control to the converted `DataTable`

Here is the code to convert your dictionary to a datatable

```
    ///
    ///Converts a Dictionary of the given type to a DataTable
    ///     
    public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(Dictionary<string, T> list, string dataTableName)
    {
        DataTable table = CreateTable1<T>(dataTableName);
        Type entityType = typeof(T);
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entityType);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, T> item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();

            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                {
                    if (prop.GetValue(item.Value) == null)
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item.Value).ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item.Value);
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
    ///
    /// Create a DataTable wich columns based on the properties of the given type <T>
    ///
    public static DataTable CreateTable<T>(string dataTableName)
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(T);
        DataTable table = new DataTable(dataTableName);
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entityType);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but then the values would be in the columns, but I need them in the rows. I tried a bit around, changed the dict to <int, sting> and so I am able to bin against ReplacementText[i]

Answer (score 0):

```
Also, the entries in the ReplacementText dictionary are dynamic (i.e. the user can add more keys, which then also should be visible in the datagrid)
```

You cannot bind on  dictionary object in `TwoWay` mode  as it's `Key` and `Value` properties are read-only. however you can replace your dictionary part using this code

```
 public class KeyValueRow<K,V>:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public  KeyValueRow(K key,V value)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Value = value; 
        }
        private K _key;
        private V _value;  
             
        public K Key
        {
            get { return _key;  }
            set
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<K>.Default.Equals(_key, value)) 
                {
                    _key = value;  
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Key");
                }
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));  
        }
        public V Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<V>.Default.Equals(_value, value))
                {
                   _value = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }              
        //prefarble way  as it evit to check the for null when raising  event 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate{};

    }
```

and instead of Dictionary  you can use

```
 public ObservableCollection<KeyValueRow<string, string>> ReplacementText { get; set; }
```

and finally  apply  the master details scenario like in  [this](http://nositesleft.com/wpf-master-detail-example-using-mvvm/)  example

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Julie! I do not need to change the entries in the dict, I just need to change the content of the Value of the irems in the dict. I did change the classes a bit, so I am able to bind against ReplacementText[0]. Unfortunately ReplacementText["Name"] doesn't work, because you can't use exclamation marks in the binding.